# Sending GregorianCalendar by Socket in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, client-server, gregorian-calendar

I'm facing the problem of passing custom serialized class by Socket in my Android application written in Kotlin language. As far as I managed to resolve the problem is in GregorianCalendar class which is passed in my TakeKeyUserEvent class. The problem is no longer present when i'm not passing GregorianCalendar object in my class.

Client:

```
        val event = TakeKeyUserEvnet(u,r,date)
        val s: Socket = Socket(IP,PORT)
        val out: ObjectOutputStream = ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream())
        out.writeObject(event)
        out.flush()
        out.close()
```

Server:

```
thread(start = true) {
            val ss: ServerSocket = ServerSocket(PORT)

            while(true){
                clientSocket = ss.accept()

                val input = ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream())

                val event: UserEvent = input.readObject() as UserEvent //error happens here

                readMessage(event)
            }
        }
```

TakeKeyUserEvent class:

```
    class TakeKeyUserEvent(val user: User, val room: Room, val date: GregorianCalendar): UserEvent() { //Works perfectly without GregorianCalendar class
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic private val serialVersionUID: Long = 7571062817744602394L
    }
}
```

UserEvent class:

```
    abstract class UserEvent: Serializable {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        private val serialVersionUID: Long = 7571062817744602394L
    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: libcore.util.ZoneInfo; Incompatible class (SUID): libcore.util.ZoneInfo: static final long serialVersionUID =-4598738130123921552L; but expected libcore.util.ZoneInfo: static final long serialVersionUID =5684813000093210627L;
```

I've tried to create my own GregorianCalendar class that inherits from original one and set my serialVersionUID but it did not help. I'll be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by passing time in millis (as Long value) and then changing it to GregorianCalendar object. It work perfectly now. I know it is kind of work-around so if You have better solution please share it with others.